# Geolocator causing Abort on PositionChanged Event

Tags: c#, geolocation, windows-phone

I'm having a problem with the geolocator where when I set MovementThreshold to 1, everything is ok but if I set it to 0 then I get an Abort error when listening for the position event change

```
Geolocator Locator = new Geolocator();
Locator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
Locator.MovementThreshold = 0;
Locator.PositionChanged += Locator_PositionChanged; // Error occours here but does not occour if Threshold >= 1
```

Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the MovementTreshold to 0 is the same as not setting it anyway and if it is unset you can not use the position/status-changed events. You will always get an exception in this case.

Comment: ah so its not like the GeoWatcher where you set it to zero and it will cause the position change to fire off constantly?

Comment: You can use ReportInterval to set a timeinterval to get data from GeoLocator. Maybe it could be better for you

Comment: Was it what you looked for?